How can I identify the most common sequences of method calls in Java project?
How can I identify the most common sequences of method calls in my Java project? While I know how to find usages of a single method in IntelliJ or Eclipse, I'm looking for a straightforward way to determine which sequences of methods are frequently used together.

For example, given I have the below java class:
public class Helpers {

    public static void method0(){}
    public static void method1(){}
    public static void method2(){}
    public static void method3(){}
}

and then this methods are used in a test class as below:
public class AppTest extends TestCase {

    private final Helpers helpers = new Helpers();
    public void AppTest( String testName )
    {
        helpers.method0();
        helpers.method1();
    }

    public void AppTest1(String testName )
    {
        helpers.method0();
        helpers.method2();
    }

    public void AppTest2(String testName )
    {
        helpers.method0();
        helpers.method1();
    }
}

So, the most common pattern of usage in this should be:
Sequence length 1: method0();
Sequence length 2: method0(); method1();


What I have tried:
I noticed there is a library in python called javalang which is able to parse java code and i can develop my own snippet to analyze java projects,however i guess there should be an easier way or existing tools which does this !

I remember that TCC had similar feature. It allowed to spot similar spinets of code across project. Never saw it in any other IDE. Unfortunately TCC is long dead.

@Jeff What about using a profiler?

@Progman and how profiler will help? Unless you willing to parse profiler result to collect that statistic, but I doubt it will be much easier then parsing java. Also I think there are more libraries that help to parse java then profiler output.
